# Implementing callbacks in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am working on a set of "generic" classes I use frequently in different AS3 projects. One of these classes is the Image class (extends MovieClip) which simply takes an URL, generates a loader than loads it and adds it as a child. In the aim of making it more generic, I thought of adding a callback as a parameter that could contain certain messages related to resizing the image and such (I can't resize any Image before the loader inside it is loaded since it's width and height will be 0 until then so it's necessary to wait for loading and handling such operations using event listeners in parent MovieClips is not convenient if there's a huge amount of images being loaded).

Here is my current implementation:

```
public class Image extends MovieClip {

    public var self:MovieClip; //fixes scope issues when nesting functions
    private var url:String;
    private var callback:Function;

    public function Image(url:String, callback:Function) {
        this.self = this; //fixes scope issues when nesting functions
        this.url = url;
        this.callback = callback;
        this.loadAndDraw();
    }

    public function loadAndDraw():void {
        var l:Loader = new Loader();
        l.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function doneLoading(evt:Event) {
            self.addChild(evt.currentTarget.loader); 
            callback();
        });
        l.load(new URLRequest(this.url));
    }

}
```

Now, the problem with this is I'm having trouble writing the callback functions. I'm uncertain about how am I meant to refer to the 'caller', which makes me think there's a better way of doing this. What do you suggest?

Comment: Why not just dispatch an event once the load is complete?

Comment: Say I have three MovieClips with around 34 completely different children Images being loaded at the same time: events would be firing everywhere, and you'd have to be _really_ careful when handling them, removing handlers from the parents once all their children are loaded (which means you'd have to count the events received and check if they come from an Image yourself are actually trying to load or if they come from somewhere else)... Callbacks seem to be a more elegant, 'encapsulated' solution.

Comment: callbacks are definitely not more elegant and they to have to be removed to avoid being called unexpectedly. They also make your code difficult to debug as compiler and runtime checks can't define their scope so in case of error you are on your own to find out where those error are. The Event system is the right way to do it and is elegant and easy to work with. Some people can't wrap their head around it and can only use callbacks.

Comment: Solving this particular problem using the Event system requires 20 extra very confusing lines of code. Also, I don't see how callbacks could be called unexpectedly in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass a reference to the `Image` instance in the callback function.

```
public class Image extends MovieClip {

    public var self:MovieClip; //fixes scope issues when nesting functions
    private var url:String;
    private var callback:Function;

    public function Image(url:String, callback:Function) {
        this.self = this; //fixes scope issues when nesting functions
        this.url = url;
        this.callback = callback;
        this.loadAndDraw();
    }

    public function loadAndDraw():void {
        var l:Loader = new Loader();
        l.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function doneLoading(evt:Event) {
            self.addChild(evt.currentTarget.loader); 
            callback(self);
        });
        l.load(new URLRequest(this.url));
    }

}
```

Then, your `callback` function would have to accept that as a parameter:

```
var someImage:Image = new Image("http://some.valid.url/image.jpg", someCallback);
private function someCallback($caller:Image):void
{
    // do something with $caller...
}
```